# Retrieve data based on specified format

Tags: sql

I have a table with the configuration to

```
|Format|Value|Number
|%v-%n |A    |1
|%v %n |B    |2
|%v(%n)|C    |3
|%v    |D    |4
|%n    |E    |5
|%v%%n |F    |6
```

Using this configuration the result should be as follows (%v -> value %n - Number)

```
A-1
B 2
C(3)
D
5
F%6
```

I can do this using a case statement by including all known combinations like

```
CASE WHEN format = '%v-%n' THEN VALUE || '-' || NUMBER END
```

How can I make it generic to accept any combination rather than hardcoding things in a case statement?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: wx2. But I dont want to tag it as I am looking for a database agnostic solution.

Comment: This should work in most DBMS: `replace(replace(format, '%v', value), '%n', number)`

Comment: Please post it as an answer. Although it doesnt work in WX2, I should be able to kick off from here using this pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I tested this out with mysql:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(format, '%v', value), '%n', number) from format;
```

I hope this helps!